# Does the browser have to recalculate an SVG element with every frame refresh

Tags: javascript, css, svg

So apparently browsers refresh at 60 FPS, so what I was wondering is if a webpage has a lot of SVG elements whether or not the browser has to calculate an SVG element with each refresh or if the browser just runs the SVG element once then maps the pixels to the pages XY coordinates.

Comment: That's implementation dependent. What answer are you looking for?

Comment: these days, it's almost assuredly calc'd once and cached, either to a layer or just as a layed out dom.

Comment: @dandavis, ok good because the app I am making is pretty interactive and i don't want to overload the browser.